# Issue with getting GestureDetector to work with handleMessage

Tags: android, gesturedetector

my app shows a bunch of bitmaps that animate one by one as it's stored in a Bitmap array and initially when app starts up curPosition is 0 to start animating obj at index 0. The handleMessage will animate each obj with a 1000ms delay between each obj when app starts up first time and so when app starts up first time handleMessage animates each obj normally.

The issue is once I double tap the restart button bitmap. I used the GestureDetector class and I have a Restart button constructed via a bitmap that when I listen for onDoubleTap and what should happen is the handleMessage will go thru each bitmap restarting animating them.

For some reason, when I double tap the Restart button bitmap, the handleMessage is running and i know this since I put in a logcat message and for that logcat message in update method I see it running thru each curPosition so I mean this line: Log.i ("cur pos. so far:", "" + curPosition );

but I don't visually see the animation running thru update method unless I interrupt app (i.e. close app OR minimize then resume app) and double tap the Restart button bitmap and the double tapping Restart button bitmap WORKS ONLY ONCE so I need to interrupt app to get it to work again.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity  implements
    GestureDetector.OnGestureListener,
    GestureDetector.OnDoubleTapListener {

private MySurfaceView mysurfaceView;

private Bitmap restart_buttonBitmap;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private MiniProj2Button restart;
private MiniProj2Button newLevel;

private final int SIZE = 5;
private final int DELAY = 1000;
private Bitmap[] myObjs = new Bitmap[ SIZE ];

//Screen size info
private int screenWidth;
private int screenHeight;
//The size in pixels of a place on the game board
private int blockSize;
private int numBlocksWide;
private int numBlocksHigh;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mySurfaceView);

    // Create a GestureDetector
    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(this, this);

    // Attach listeners that'll be called for double-tap and related gestures
    mGestureDetector.setOnDoubleTapListener( this );

}//END METHOD: onCreate

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Log.d("onStop", "Main Activity's onStop called");
    gameView.surfaceDestroyed( mySurfaceView.getHolder() );
    this.finish();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Log.d("onResume", "Main Activity's onResume called");

    mySurfaceView = new MySurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(mySurfaceView);
    mySurfaceView.surfaceCreated( mySurfaceView.getHolder() );
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Log.i("onPause", "Main Activity's onPause called");
    mySurfaceView.surfaceDestroyed( mySurfaceView.getHolder() );
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {

    //reset animation if Restart button pressed!
    if ( restart.isButtonTouched(e.getX(), e.getY(), blockSize,blockSize)  ) {

        curPosition = 0;

    }

    return true;
}

public void configureDisplay() {
    //find out the width and height of the screen
    Display display =
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    screenWidth = size.x;
    screenHeight = size.y;

    //Determine the size of each block/place on the board
//        blockSize = screenWidth/10;
    blockSize = screenWidth/10;

    //Determine how many blocks will fit into the
    //height and width
//        numBlocksWide = 10;
    numBlocksWide = 10;
    numBlocksHigh = ( ( screenHeight ) ) / blockSize;


}//END METHOD: configureDisplay

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e) {
    mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(e);
    return super.onTouchEvent(e);

}//END onTouchEvent

class MySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, Handler.Callback {

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;//this lets us access the canvas but still need to use Canvas class
    Handler myHandler;
    Paint paint = new Paint ();

    public MySurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 0, 0, 0));
        path = new Path ();
        myHandler = new Handler(this);
        getHolder().addCallback(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        this.surfaceHolder = holder;
        myHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,
                               int format, int width, int height) {
        // What do I enter here???
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        Log.i("Me", "surfaceDestroyed: bye!" );
        myHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
    }

    protected void drawIt ( ) {

        if ( surfaceHolder.getSurface().isValid() ) {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);//the background

            //for each obj, draw it

            surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }//END IF BLOCK: For valid surfaceHolder
    }//END METHOD: drawIt

    public void update() {
        Log.i ("cur pos. so far:", "" + curPosition );

        if ( curPosition < SIZE ) {
            myObjs [ curPosition ].animateMe ( );
            curPosition++;
        }


    }//END METHOD: update


    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {

        if (curPosition < SIZE  ) {
            Log.i("Still objs 2 animate","Yes");
            Log.i ("cur pos. so far:", "" + curPosition );
            gameView.update();
            gameView.drawIt();
            myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(msg.what, DELAY);
        }

        else {
            myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(msg.what, 10);
            gameView.drawIt();
        }

        return true;
    }//END METHOD: handleMessage

}//END INNER CLASS: MySurfaceView
}//END CLASS: MainActivity
```

Comment: Is my explanation clear? Please let me know.

Comment: I got rid of using GestureDetector and just checked when ACTION_DOWN in onTouchEvent method and same issue, I have to close app or minimize app in order to see the animation when I press Restart button? So it seems this line: myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(msg.what, DELAY) is not running UNLESS I close app or minimize and resume app and even then, I can ONLY tap the Restart button ONCE to see this line run: myHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(msg.what, DELAY). Please help